# Gitlab on Ubuntu: incomplete install?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, gitlab, ubuntu-16.04

Gitlab 8.5.8 installed on Ubuntu 16.04, through apt-get (NOT the Omnibus install). INstallation was fraught (essentially because of https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gitlab/+bug/1574349, which required workarounds). However it came to an end with most stuff working (the one I tried so far, that is). However I suspect the installation is not complete. Here is why:

1) the commands gitlab-rails and gitlab-ctl are nowhere to be found, yet they are all over the gitlab site doc. I suspect that gitlab-rails may be present as /usr/share/gitlab/bin/rails , but hve no way to confirm (and that still leaves the gitlab-ctl question).

2) Email notifications (e.g. on user add)  are not being sent even after going through the config files. When I try the test suggested in https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/settings/smtp.md#gmail (using the rails command above, as gitlab-rails is not there), I get:

```
# /usr/share/gitlab/bin/rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.7.1)
irb(main):001:0> Notify.test_email('destination_email@address.com', 'Message Subject', 'Message Body').deliver_now
NameError: uninitialized constant Notify
    from (irb):1
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/share/gitlab/bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from /usr/share/gitlab/bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I know bubke about ruby, but the error message makes me think that I am either running the wrong console (see point 1) or that some library (containing the NOtify class, for instance) is missing form the install.

Google is not helping and I am somewhat stymied: can this be fixed? Need I wipe everything and go Omnibus (which irks me, becauseI'd rather have an apt managed install)?

Somebody pointed me to this guide: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-gitlab-on-ubuntu-16-04 It may or may not be the Omnibus install, but imporved in that it  would appear to funnel the install through apt)

Suggestions appreciated.